# Isn't windowsoftinputmode = adjustResize supposed to move ALL the activity window to make room for the keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, window-soft-input-mode

I'm working on a chat feature for an app an stumbled across the following issue.

I have an activity with `android:windowsotinputmode = "stateHidden|adjustResize"` (when the activity starts, the keyboard doesn't pop automatically up but waits until the user taps on the editText to type his message and after, the whole activity screen should slide up and make room for the soft keyboard).

However...

[image]

I noticed that the activity only slides up until the keyboard is right below the editText, covering the 'random view' at the bottom of the activity.

Is there a way to override this and make the screen move up completely and make visible the whole activity?

[EDIT] I should also mention that setting any paddingBottom/marginBottom to the editText gets ignored as well as the view.

Comment: what do you mean by "screen pop up completly"?

Comment: I meant for the screen to 'move up' all of it together with the 'random view' or any padding might be there

Answer (score 0):

You could go through this link and the code,could help you:

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edtInput"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:maxLength="2000"
        android:hint="@string/compose_hint"/>
```